# Missing variable name while trying to send sheet row data to GmailApp; Javascript/Google App script

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, response

Still on a learning curve here. I am trying to get data from a google sheet and send the data Gmail app but getting Missing variable name error. This is what I have tried for the last 2 hours and I will appreciate help in structuring the code to work.

```
function emailTheLastRow(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
   var range = sheet.getRange("AO2:AO"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var searchString = "1";

  for (var i = 0; i<range.length; i++) {
  if(range[i][0] == searchString) {
   var lastRow = sheet.getRange(2+i,1,1,41).getValues();
     var data = {    
       'email':lastRow[0][1],
       'project':lastRow[0][2],
       'client':lastRow[0][3],
       'sdate':lastRow[0][4],
       'edate':lastRow[0][5],
       'loe':lastRow[0][7],
     };

      GmailApp.sendEmail("test@gmail.com", "Project", "A new project has been created with the following details: " + data());

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think instead of calling Project_Name(), you may call simply as Project_Name [ without parenthesis].

Comment: There is no variable called "lastRow". My guess is that you might have meant to declare the range, then declare `var lastRow = range.getValues();`

Comment: And please check spaces between different variables like in "var Project_start date = lastRow[0][4]" and "var Project_end date = lastRow[0][5]"

Comment: Hi @KhurramIshaque, I have edited the code above now, but I now get an error on line 9 where **GmailApp** is. The error is **TypeError: [object Object] is not a function, it is object** What could I be doing wrong. Again feel free to rewrite the code to help me see what am not seeing.

Comment: Simply data is an object. You need to create a string to gather all details and append with the "A new project...." string. Example: var projectData = "Email = " + data.email + "<br/>" + "Project = " + data.project + "<br/>"; // likewise you may append other fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate a string with a JSON, which is an object and not a string. Use `stringify` function [1] to convert the object to a string. Add this line after you declare `data` variable:

```
 data = JSON.stringify(data);
```

[1] https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Comment: Thanks, @Andres, but String may not be invoked as a function when I add this line.  **data = JSON.stringify(data);** another error is thrown in the line     GmailApp.sendEmail("test@gmail.com", "Project", "A new project has been created with the following details: " + data());

Comment: Hey @Andres, Fortunately after enclosing data in single bracket. It worked. Thanks for the help "Master"  :-)